# Powershell return value from function driving me crazy

Tags: powershell

I know, there are hundreds of pages that address the -in my opinion- strange way that Powershell handles return values from functions, and I must have visited about half of them ;=)

This particular one drives me nuts.
Consider the following:

I'm doing a call to a function with one parameter (call is not done from within another function):

```
$result = getVMinfo($vm)
```

The function getVMinfo looks like this :

```
function getVMinfo {
  param (
    [string]$vm
  )
  try {
    Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_DiskDrive -Computername $vm -ErrorAction Stop
  }
  catch {
    $ErrorReturn = $_.Exception.Message
  }
  if ($ErrorReturn) {
    Write-Host "Error =" $ErrorReturn
    return $ErrorReturn
  }
}
```

Looks simple enough, and other functions do work when returning a value in this way.
Now, if I run the script, The `write-Host` bit in the `catch` *does* show me that `$ErrorReturn` is filled with a string (tested that with `$ErrorReturn.GetType()` ).
However, `$result` in the calling statement is always empty.
I have tried many suggestions, like creating an array, and use the `.Add()` to add the errorstring to the array, and then return the array. Nothing seems to work.
I am really at a loss here. Don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Please, help me !

Comment: Could be that the error message for the exception in question is an empty string (thus evaluating to `$false`). Have you tried capturing the error record itself instead? `$ErrorReturn = $_`, then outside the `catch` block `if($ErrorReturn){Write-Host "Error = " $ErrorReturn.Exception.Message}`

Comment: And this, ladies and gentlemen, is why you don't attempt to assert truthiness of non-boolean expressions.

Comment: What type does `Get-Member -InputObject $result` indicate? Generally, the simplest way to get an error record's message is to use its stringification: `$ErrorReturn = "$_"`.